# Why does my SPARQL query works in idref but not in R?

Tags: r, sparql

I am trying to extract SPARQL data with SPARQL package in R. This works in https://data.idref.fr/yasgui.html but not in R :

```
SPARQL(url="https://data.idref.fr/sparql", 
query='PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX bnf-onto: <http://data.bnf.fr/ontology/bnf-onto/> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT ?nom count(*) as ?prefaces
WHERE 
{
    <http://www.idref.fr/028479653/id> foaf:name ?nom. 
    ?uri ?relator <http://www.idref.fr/028479653/id> ; dcterms:bibliographicCitation ?titre. 
    ?relator skos:prefLabel ?role. 
    FILTER CONTAINS(?role, "Préfacier, etc.")
}')
```

This returns the following error :

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: I don't know R well enough to tell you how to fix this, but the error indicates that it doesn't know how to deal with the SSL certificate provided by the server. So I'd have a look around for examples on how to connect to HTTP-Secure sites from R.